# re to construct javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function that checks selected div ids, and performs an action if a particular div is present:

```
function checkContent_m(){
var mItems = [document.getElementById('m_round1'),document.getElementById('m_round2'),document.getElementById('m_round3'),document.getElementById('m_round4'),
document.getElementById('m_round5'),document.getElementById('m_round6'),document.getElementById('m_round7'),document.getElementById('m_round8')];

if (mItems.length > 0){
        document.getElementById('m_div').style.display = "block";       
}
else{
    document.getElementById('m_div').style.display = "none";
}
```

}

Seems to me that there might be a way for me to construct my array more efficiently. How would I construct a regular expression that would be an equivalent to:

```
document.getElementById('m_round'+ '*')
```

Such statement would allow me to add an unlimited number of "m_round" divs, without having to modify my js function.

Comment: The traditional wisdom here is to apply a common class to all the elements you want and then select them with `document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")`.

Comment: That would only work in browsers that support HTML5.

Comment: Why do you test `mItems.length > 0`? It is always true.

Comment: do not use ids for that, a better practice would be to use ``data-*`` attributes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using jQuery. Then selecting ID's that have similar names is trivial...

```
$('[id^="m_round"]')
```

Of course, you could also give all the elements you want to select the same class and then select them that way...

```
$('.m_round')
```

Comment: and that syntax would be something like "var = $('[id^="m_round"]');" ?

Comment: Yep, that will get you a jQuery object that represents all elements with and ID that contains `m_round`. @kjarsenal

Comment: just tested this. works like a fricken charm! I'm grateful, thank you.